# Good word/phrase that describes the "process of duplication"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What can be a good word/phrase for describing the process of duplication?

More specifically, this is what I want to convey:

*Machines are good at tasks that involve copy-pasting*.

What can be a good word/phrase that would say, *Machines are good at data ____*

PS: words considered: Data replication,

Comment: What was it that you didn't like about data replication?

Answer (score 1):

Data duplication does fit perfectly. According to OED duplication is "the action or process of duplicating something."

You could also use copying or regurgitation or repetition, depending on the context.

Comment: I might add "blindly copy," if the point is that errors will persist between duplications.

Answer (score 0):

Copy in this context implies duplication. I would say "copying data" works best.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, and explain *why* and *how* "copying data" might work best in this context. Also provide corroboration, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- "Repetitive tasks"
- "Duplication"
- "Iteration" / "iterating"

In the context of your example sentence, you could put;
"Machines are good at transferring large amounts of data"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps data duplication, data cloning, data copying, data replication or data forging? They all involve making a copy from the original data.

I would personally say something along the lines of

> Machines are good at (executing) repetitive tasks.

Although it's not specifically conveying copying and pasting, I think it gets the point across.